# Summing grouped items in a numpy array without looping

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to sum those non-zero values in array `a` that have the same value in array `label` and then replace them with 0 but only one of them with their sum:

```
import numpy as np
a =    np.array([[0,0,0,5,5,0],
                 [1,1,0,2,2,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,2,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,3,3,3]])

label = np.array([[0,1,2,3,3,3],
                  [1,1,4,4,4,3],
                  [1,4,4,5,4,6],
                  [1,4,4,4,7,8],
                  [9,5,5,5,5,5]])

#should produce the following result:
result =        [[0,0,0,0,0,10],
                 [2,0,0,0,6,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,9,0]]
```

it doesn't matter where we replace the sum. 
I couldn't think of any other way than looping.

```
a_ = a.ravel()
labels_ = labels.ravel()
list_of_labels = np.unique(label[a>0])

for item in list_of_labels:
     summ = np.sum(a_[np.argwhere((a_> 0) & (labels_ == item))])
     print summ
```

Comment: I am not getting your question , you want to sum values in array 'a' basis on ? wht do you mean by same value in array 'label' ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul array `label` groups items of array `a` into separate chunks. For example sum of items in array `a` where they are grouped in `label` by number `4`.

Comment: can you give example for this column ' [1,1,0,2,2,0]' in array 'a' ? how it giving two sum in final result '                 [2,0,0,0,6,0],'

Comment: looking at array `label`, we for example are interested in items that are equal to 1. We simply sum corresponding items in array `a` which will be 0+1+1+0+0+0 = 2. The same for items in array `label` that are equal to 4 will be 0+2+2+2+0+0+0+0+0 = 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the sums using `np.bincount` with the `weights` parameter. If I'm not mistaken `np.bincount` is O(n) as is the rest of the code below:

```
# get the sums
cnts = np.bincount(label.ravel(), a.ravel())
# next two lines get indices of the last occurrence of each label
psns = np.full(cnts.shape, -1, dtype=int)
psns[label.ravel()] = range(label.size)
# now plug the sums at the appropriate positions
resflat = np.zeros((a.size + 1,), dtype=a.dtype)
resflat[psns] = cnts
result = resflat[:-1].reshape(a.shape)
result
# array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 10],
#        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
#        [ 2,  0,  0,  6,  0,  0],
#        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  9]])
```

Comment: The solution works, but when I try it for another example (with `a.shape = (20,20)` I got this error: `resflat[psns] = cnts
IndexError: index 31850831 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 400`. The number for index changes every time that I run the same code.

Comment: Replaced `psns = np.empty(...)` with `psns=np.zeros(...)` and it worked

Comment: @BehzadJamali That probably means there are missing labels. Your solution is only correct if the sum for label `0` is actually `0`. Is that the case?

Comment: I actually will have no `0` in my `label` array. I'm creating label by skimage         `label = measure.label(another_array, connectivity=1, background= -1)`

Comment: @BehzadJamali I've made some changes could you please check if they work for you?